80s horror movie identification
It seemed to be a friday the 13th knock off, a bunch of kids at a summer camp suffering accidents and being killed off one by one. I never saw the end but i remember a scene where a bathroom stall was locked the window screen was cut and a wasps nest was thrown in. I hope this help, i havent seen it in a long time and want to see how it ends

From the little I see here, you could be talking about:
Sleepaway Camp(1983)
Here is the link to the scene I believe you were talking about if it helps!



